# ssrs multiple datasets - master detail

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm working on migrating all of our reporting solutions to SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2.  I have a problem with one of the reports which builds a CP12 - for readers outside the UK, this is a Gas Safety certificate.  The report has two data sets, one containing the tenant and landlord details, the other containing a list of appliances.  The list of appliances are displayed in groups of 5 in the centre of the page with the tenant and landlord details at the top and bottom.  The problem is when there are more than 5 appliances the report splits over multiple pages, I need the surrounding tenant and landlord details to be repeated - a bit like a header and footer.  Can anyone help suggest a good approach?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I recommend combining the datasets into a single dataset, putting the appliances into a detail row, and the tenant and landlord data into header and footer rows; then set the RepeatOnNewPage property of the header and footer rows to be True.